# Copy last numeric part of a file name to the beginning

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

```
ISS45_20200302030042.zip
R0387F200229.zip
```

I want a shell script for this scenario. Above are the two file names I want something like this. I want digits part to be prepended to the front of the filename for both of these. See example below for what I want:

```
20200302030042_ISS45_20200302030042.zip
200229_R0387F200229.zip
```

```
for f in *.zip; do
   mv "$f" $(sed -E 's/^(.+)_([^.]+)\./\2_\1./' <<< "$f")
done
```

I am using this. It is working fine only for `iss45` file but not for `R` file.

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62180668/3776858

Comment: Let's keep this one; I just fixed the formatting ;-)

Comment: Your code does not rename `ISS45_20200302030042.zip` to `20200302030042_ISS45_20200302030042.zip` but to `20200302030042_ISS45.zip`. So which do you want?

Comment: @Theophrastus I was trying to achieve what I explained above but I unfortunately i can't

Comment: @HaukeLaging I want both file names like this:
20200302030042_ISS45_20200302030042.zip
200229_R0387F200229.zip

Comment: @Theophrastus yes there is no underscore in the R filename. Code I shared was only for ISS45 file which is also not working perfectly for ISS45 file as well. And for R file I am not able to write code to handle this R file scenario.

Comment: @Theophrastus yeah that is what i was trying to do but unfortunately i was not able to do that. I can use separate commands for both file name. So if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `sed` command you need:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)([^[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]+)\.zip$/\3_\1\2\3.zip/'
```

```
$ echo ISS45_20200302030042.zip |
    sed -r 's/^(.*)([^[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]+)\.zip$/\3_\1\2\3.zip/'
20200302030042_ISS45_20200302030042.zip

$ echo R0387F200229.zip |
    sed --posix -r 's/^(.*)([^[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]+)\.zip$/\3_\1\2\3.zip/'
200229_R0387F200229.zip
```

Comment: Looks like we had very similar ideas :-)

Comment: @bxm Not surprising. There are only so many useful approaches to such a simple problem.

Comment: thanks very much @HaukeLaging it worked

Comment: @HaukeLaging. I need a little more help. File name is now 200229_R0387F200229.zip for R file. I want to append 20 at start of only R file. So that file name will become 20200229_R0387F200229.zip

Comment: @user3199894 That is an unsusable description of what you want. You don't have just these two file names. For if you had just them you could just hardcode the `mv` commands... So what exactly defines the file(s) for this special treatment? This exact name? Any file name starting with `R`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Perl-ish version of rename available (even if you don’t, the regex should work with `sed -r`.)

```
rename 's/^(.*[^0-9]+)([0-9]+)([.]zip)$/$2_$1$2$3/' *.zip
```

Logically divides the name into three sections, from right to left: the extension `$3`, the numeric block before the extension `$2` and everything that preceded it `$1`.

Then stitch back together with `$2` prepended.

Comment: I need a little more help. File name is now 200229_R0387F200229.zip for R file. I want to append 20 at start of only R file. So that file name will become 20200229_R0387F200229.zip

Comment: OK, that wasn't mentioned before so I didn't try to account for it :-) Please update your question with the new requirement (that's the standard model here, rather than just mentioning things in comments).  I'm surmising these numerics you are moving about represent dates and that you'd be looking for a solution that isn't purely 2020 centric? If so, please include this info in the question.